# Why does Late Initialization Error occur?

Tags: flutter, dart

The application has the function of adding news to favorites. But when I go to the Favorites page, I get the error "Late Initialization Error: Field "article" has not been initialized.

The problem is in the button "Details", in the line:

```
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ArticlePage(article: article,))
```

Please help me solve the problem. Below is the code for this page:

```
class FavScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FavScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FavScreen> createState() => _FavScreenState();
}

class _FavScreenState extends State<FavScreen> {
  late final Article article;
  final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('favoriteItems');

  @override
  void initState() {
    article = Article(
      author: article.author,
      title: article.title,
      description: article.description,
      url: article.url,
      urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
      publishedAt: article.publishedAt,
      content: article.content,
      source: article.source,
    );
    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Favorite News', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfff27935),
      ),
      body:
         StreamBuilder(
           stream: _fireStore.snapshots(),
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
             if(!snapshot.hasData) {
               return Text('No featured news');
             } else {
               return ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     return InkWell(
                       child: Container(
                         margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.white,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                             boxShadow: [
                               BoxShadow(
                                 color: Colors.black12,
                                 blurRadius: 3.0,
                               ),
                             ]),
                         child: Column(
                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                           children: [
                             Container(
                               height: 200.0,
                               width: double.infinity,
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                 image: DecorationImage(
                                     image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('image')), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Container(
                                 child: Row(
                                     textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                     children: <Widget>[
                                       Container(
                                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                           color: Color(0xfff27935),
                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                         ),
                                         child: Text(
                                           snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('name'),
                                           style: TextStyle(
                                             color: Colors.white,
                                           ),
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                       IconButton(
                                           onPressed: () {
                                             _fireStore.doc(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id).delete();
                                           },
                                           icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_remove)),
                                     ]
                                 )
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 8.0,
                             ),
                             Text(
                               snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('title'),
                               style: TextStyle(
                                 fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                 fontSize: 16.0,
                               ),
                             ),
                             SizedBox(
                               height: 10.0,
                             ),
                             GestureDetector(
                               onTap: () {
                                 Navigator.push(
                                     context,
                                     MaterialPageRoute(
                                         builder: (context) =>
                                             ArticlePage(
                                               article: article,
                                             )));
                               },
                               child: new Text("DETAILS", style: TextStyle(
                                 fontSize: 12.0,
                                 ),
                               ),
                             )
                           ],
                         ),
                       ),
                     );
                   }
               );
             }
           },
         )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove final ....

Comment: In your `initState()` you are trying to initialize `article` by passing itself as parameters.

Comment: Third time within 48h for the same question. It's already been explained to you.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
    article = Article(
      author: article.author,
      title: article.title,
      description: article.description,
      url: article.url,
      urlToImage: article.urlToImage,
      publishedAt: article.publishedAt,
      content: article.content,
      source: article.source,
    );
```

You're trying to initialize `article` by creating a new `Article` with values from `article`. `article` is uninitialized however, so it fails to read these values and spits out an error.

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve, but I guess you want to pass in an `Article` into the widget and initialize the `article` variable in your state class with that?

Comment: I need to transfer the article to the widget so that clicking on "Details" opens the full article. I already have this implemented on the main page, but I can't do it on the Favorites page, this error is highlighted